# ng-table pagination button not displaying

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

The pagination buttons are not showing up in my html page.

Below is the html page.

```
<div id="home">
    <table ng-table="homeVm.customConfigParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}</td>
            <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the controller page:

```
 function HomeController(NgTableParams) {
        var vm = this;
var data = [ {name: "Moroni", age: 50},  {name: "Moroni", age: 50}, /*....*/]

function createUsingFullOptions() {
            var initialParams = {
                count: 10, // initial page size
            };
            var initialSettings = {
                // page size buttons (right set of buttons in demo)
                counts: [],
                // determines the pager buttons (left set of buttons in demo)
                paginationMaxBlocks: 3,
                paginationMinBlocks: 2,
                dataset: data
            };
            return new NgTableParams(initialParams, initialSettings);
        }
```

I need to display the pagination buttons.

Below is the output of the page.
[image]

Comment: please provide a plunk for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed css file. As you can see in the snippet, pagination is working fine.

> Also you should have **more data than item count per page** for pagination
>   to appear.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);
var data = [ {name: "Moroni", age: 50},  {name: "Moroni1", age: 50}]
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,NgTableParams) {
  
  var initialParams = {
                count: 1, // initial page size
            };
            var initialSettings = {
                // page size buttons (right set of buttons in demo)
                counts: [],
                // determines the pager buttons (left set of buttons in demo)
                paginationMaxBlocks: 3,
                paginationMinBlocks: 2,
                dataset: data
            };
            $scope.customConfigParams =  new NgTableParams(initialParams, initialSettings);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <table ng-table="customConfigParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}</td>
            <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Pagination is still not showing up even if the css file is used.

Comment: do you have more data than you have per page count?

Comment: Yes i do have around 30 data, and the count is set to 10.

The only problem is that pagination is not showing up. when i inspect on the html, i can see that the pagination divs appear but not on the screen

Comment: have you used bootstrap css? may be one of your pages styles are hiding them. its not angular problem if there is no ng-hide class on the pagination.

Comment: I have used foundation css

Comment: include bootstrap css and check if pagination appear

Comment: I imported boostrap css. Pagination still does not appear.